# Indicar correctamente el base_path() en Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo pruebas en *deploy*.

Hace unos días lo hice de la siguiente manera, subí los archivos en mi hosting CPanel a la raíz, es decir, `/home/miproyecto` y lo de la carpeta pública en `/home/miproyecto/public_html`, hice el ajuste de la nueva ruta pública `en AppServiceProviders.php`.

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path('public_html');
        });
```

Todo funcionó bien, incluso las imágenes que subo lo hacen correctamente dentro de la carpeta pública.

Hoy lo hice de la misma forma, salvo que en lugar de subir el proyecto a `/home/miproyecto`, lo hice en `/home/miproyecto/laravel` para más organización.

Igualmente hice ajustes para indicar la carpeta pública y todo funciona bien, excepto que ahora el `base_path`, en lugar de quedar en `/home/miproyecto` queda en `/home/miproyecto/laravel`.

Ahora al subir las imágenes en lugar de guardarse en `/home/miproyecto/public_html/img` suben a `/home/miproyecto/laravel/public_html/img`

En el index.php hice los ajustes para que se reconozca la ruta del proyecto

```
require __DIR__ . '/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Hola Christian, he quitado la leyenda **[solucionado]** a tu pregunta porque así no funciona en SO, para marcar como solucionada tu pregunta debes marcar el icono de aceptado en la respuesta que consideres correcta

Answer (score 1):

Quedó solucionado, mi error era al regresar la ruta desde el AppServiceProvider.php, debía ser de la siguiente manera

```
public function register()
    {
       $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/../public_html'; // Forma correcta para mi caso
            //return base_path() . '/public_html'; // Forma incirrecta
        });
    }
```